# not receive email in google app engine java

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I'm writing code for receive email and change into todo. I received fresh email and converted todo but I sent forward email or reply email app engine not receive the email. What's the problem. I used session and getdefaultinstance that's all rest of the code same as receive email code.please do the needful.thanks

IN SERVLET Properties props = new Properties();

Session email = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

try 
{ 
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(email,req.getInputStream());

String summary = message.getSubject();

String description = getText(message);

Address[] addresses = message.getFrom();

User user = new User(addresses[0].toString(), "gmail.com");

Date date =new Date();

DaoComments.INSTANCE.add(addresses[0].toString(),lid,date,description,"selcom‌​ment");

}catch (Exception e) 
{ e.printStackTrace();

} 
IN WEB.XML

EmailTicket

com.cloudnowtech.EmailAgentServlet

EmailTicket

/_ah/mail/*

IN appengine-web-app

mail

HERE I'M SENDING THE CODE. PLEASE CORRECT IT –

Comment: There is no needful to do. Present your configuration settings, code etc then perhaps someone might be able to help. Adding a language tag will also encourage an answer.

Comment: IN SERVLET
     Properties props = new Properties();
     Session email = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

Comment: try {
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(email,req.getInputStream());
       String summary = message.getSubject();
       String description = getText(message);
       Address[] addresses = message.getFrom();
       User user = new User(addresses[0].toString(), "gmail.com");
       Date date =new Date();            DaoComments.INSTANCE.add(addresses[0].toString(),lid,date,description,"selcomment");

Comment: }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
IN WEB.XML
      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>EmailTicket</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cloudnowtech.EmailAgentServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
   <servlet-name>EmailTicket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
IN appengine-web-app
  <inbound-services  >
    <service>mail</service>


  </inbound-services     >

HERE I'M SENDING THE CODE. PLEASE CORRECT IT

Comment: are you able to edit the question and add it?

Answer (score 0):

An important part of sending email is to, well, to `send` it. Perhaps you missed this part:

```
// Hand the message to the default transport service for delivery.
Transport.send(msg);
```

If you take a peek over on the right there ---->,

Wander the `related` questions for yourself and you should find some helpful tidbits.
Welcome to StackOverflow and have a nice day.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not asking send mail. Asking about receiving mail. So that I'm attaching transport.send. receiving mail not received forward and reply mail

Comment: not getting proper answer. I test my mail header its having In-Reply_To and reference. its differ from new mail.but I checked google its referred In-Reply_To is a valid header. then why i'm not getting this mail and convert into todo. I checked my log it shows that mail. not converted as todo. what wrong here

Comment: ya john mee i was look around your page then only i raise this question. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. there is no setting for forward and reply email to receive. I declared field as String but reply or forward mail size as more than 500 character. so change as Text. now its working fine. thanks for all.

Thanks
Murugavel